# How to generate json with named array and unnamed objects in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm developing a RESTful web services with JAX-RS in JBoss EAP 6.1 (Resteasy 2.3.6.Final). The response of my webservice should be a JSON in the following format:

```
{"arrayName": [
   {
    "field1": "value1"
    "field2", "value2"
    "field3", "value3"
   },

   {
    "field1", "Value4"
    "field2", "value5"
    "field3", "value6"
   }
 ]
}
```

However, both Jackson and Jettison providers convert my list of objects as follows:

```
[
  {"myObjectName":
    {
      "field1":"value1",     
      "field2":"value2",     
      "field3":"value3",     
    }
  },

  {"myObjectName":
    {
      "field1":"value4",     
      "field2":"value5",     
      "field3":"value6",     
    }
  },    
]
```

I want that my array has a name and the elements within that array NOT have a name.

I managed to get the expected result using Map and Array, but it seems a terrible solution.

Can someone tell me how I can get this result in a more elegant way using the best features of JAX-RS / Resteasy?

The code is something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/myPath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyObject[] myPathJson() {
  MyObject[] myObjectArray = new MyObject[3];
  myObjectArray[0]=new MyObject();
  myObjectArray[1]=new MyObject();
  myObjectArray[2]=new MyObject();

  return myObjectArray;
}
```

Comment: The first listing isn't valid json.  Are you sure this is how you want it to render.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a object. Btw it is valid json. If it does not work you might want to try genson lib.

Comment: I updated the version of Resteasy to 3.0.9.Final and this one of my problems were solved: the objects now are not named, the output is simply {field1: "value1"}.
To name the array, then used a map it:
map.put ("arrayName" arrayObjects).
Thus, the output was as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resolve my problem I upgrade the version of Resteasy from 2.3.6.Final to 3.0.9.Final. The official documentation explain how to do this:

> 3.2. Upgrading Resteasy Within JBoss EAP 6.1
>
> Resteasy is bundled with JBoss EAP 6.1. You will likely have the need to upgrade Resteasy in JBoss EAP 6.1. The Resteasy distribution comes with a zip file called resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.9.Final.zip. Unzip this file while with the modules/system/layers/base/ directory of the JBoss EAP 6.1 distribution. This will overwrite some of the existing files there.

After upgrade the objects now are not named, the output is simply {field1: "value1"}.

To name the array, then used a map it: map.put ("arrayName" arrayObjects).

```
@GET
@Path("/myPath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<String, MyObject[]> myPathJson() {
   MyObject[] myObjectArray = new MyObject[3];
   myObjectArray[0]=new MyObject();
   myObjectArray[1]=new MyObject();
   myObjectArray[2]=new MyObject();

    Map<String, MyObject[]> namedArray = new HashMap<String, MyObject[]>();
    namedArray.put("myArrayName", myObjectArray);

    return namedArray;
}
```

Thus the response JSON is generated is as I want:

```
{"myArrayName": [
  {
"field1": "value1"
"field2", "value2"
  },
  {
"field1", "Value4"
"field2", "value5"
  }
 ]
}
```